# Table cell full size click

Tags: html, css

The table cells change color as you hover over the box and  I also need to make the box fully clickable rather than just the text in the middle without changing the height and width of the boxes. I've wrapped my divs in a tags but to no avail.

```css
div.container {
  display: table;
}
div.column {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #c2ad80;
}
div.column a {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
div.column:hover {
  background-color: #a2884f;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Solution Assessment</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Design</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Build</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Deploy</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Live (BAU)</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: why don't you use `<table>`s? also, you miss elements with `display: table-row` if you really want to augment tables.

Comment: @Joshua - Maybe because that's not tabular data  and we stopped using tables for layout back around 2000?

Comment: @Joshua It's for an IE8 Browser that I believe doesn't support HTML5

Comment: @j08691: we all do not know the context of the snippet. it could've been tabular data. augmenting tables for layouting is also nearly as bad as using real tables.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `display` property for `<a>` with either `block` or `inline-block`, as inline elements do not have box model.

```css
div.container {
  display: table;
}
div.column {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #c2ad80;
}
div.column a {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.column:hover {
  background-color: #a2884f;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Solution Assessment</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Design</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Build</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Deploy</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Live (BAU)</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's much simpler solution

```css
div.container {
  display: table;
}
div.container a {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #c2ad80;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
div.container a:hover {
  background-color: #a2884f;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Solution Assessment</a>
  <a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Design</a>
  <a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Build</a>
  <a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Deploy</a>
  <a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Test</a>
  <a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Live (BAU)</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display:block` for the links – otherwise `width` and `height` are not allowed to have any effect, because `a` is an inline element.

(And then you might want to add `line-height:100px` as well, to have the text content of the links still vertically centered.)

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with the solution having asked another bod in the office.

CSS Changes

```
div.column a {
    color:white;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I added this display: table-cell and verticle-align: middle this fixed the issue!